# Add icon to Browser tab in Quarto?

Tags: tabs, icons, quarto

I was wondering if it is possible to add an icon to your own website to show in the tab of your browser in `Quarto`? Here you can see an example of my website tab without an icon and the website of Quarto with an icon:

[image]

I can imagine there should be an option using the [Bootstrap Icons](https://icons.getbootstrap.com) as you can use in your sidebar and navigation bar. But how is this possible for the browser tab?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone coming here wondering how to add favicon to standalone HTML document, for example with quarto report with `format: html` (rather than [website built with Quarto](https://quarto.org/docs/websites/website-tools.html#social-metadata) where @Quinten's answer works well) you can add the following to your YAML header:

```
include-in-header:
  - text: |
     <link rel = "shortcut icon" href = "favicon.ico" />
```

This answer was taken from this [GitHub discussion](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/4618#discussioncomment-5220333) but took me ages to find so putting here too.

Answer (score 3):

You could use this website called [realfavicongenerator](https://realfavicongenerator.net) to generate a favicon. You only need to set the `.png` file generated on that site, in your right directory and set the name of the file in your `.yml` file like this:

```
website:
  favicon: icon.png
```

`icon.png` is the image of the favicon. It seems that now all browser are supported by what I know.

### Google Chrome

For Google chrome the result looks like this:

[image]

This works!

### Safari

When I do the same and open it in safari it returns:

[image]

As you can see it doesn't return the favicon.